# BarcodeScanner MWBInitDecoder Javascript: Undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, undefined-function

I am an iOS developer with very little Javascript experience. However, I am stuck with a problem to get a phone gap application running which is supposed to scan barcode.

I am getting an error when the barcode scanning code is invoked:
"Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

[image]

The `MWBScanner.js` file is pretty straightforward. It has got the following definition & invocation for the var `BarcodeScanner`

```
 var BarcodeScanner = {

 /**
    * Init decoder with default params.
    */
 MWBinitDecoder: function(callback) {
    cordova.exec(callback, function(){}, "MWBarcodeScanner", "initDecoder", []);
 },

 /**
    * Call the scanner screen. Result are returned in callback function as:
    * result.code - string representation of barcode result
    * result.type - type of barcode detected or 'Cancel' if scanning is canceled
    * result.bytes - bytes array of raw barcode result
    */
 MWBstartScanning: function(callback) {
 cordova.exec(callback, function(err) {
            callback('Error: ' + err);
        }, "MWBarcodeScanner", "startScanner", []);
 },

 /**
    * Registers licensing information with single selected decoder type.
    * If registering information is correct, enables full support for selected
    * decoder type.
    * It should be called once per decoder type.
    *
    * @param[in]   codeMask                Single decoder type selector (MWB_CODE_MASK_...)
    * @param[in]   userName                User name string
    * @param[in]   key                     License key string
    *
    * @retval      MWB_RT_OK               Registration successful
    * @retval      MWB_RT_FAIL             Registration failed
    * @retval      MWB_RT_BAD_PARAM        More than one decoder flag selected
    * @retval      MWB_RT_NOT_SUPPORTED    Selected decoder type or its registration
    *                                      is not supported
    */
 MWBregisterCode: function(codeMask, userName, key) {
    cordova.exec(function(){}, function(){}, "MWBarcodeScanner", "registerCode", [codeMask, userName, key]);
 },

 /**
    * Sets active or inactive status of decoder types
    *
    * @param[in]       activeCodes             ORed bit flags (MWB_CODE_MASK_...) of decoder types
    *                                          to be activated.
    */
 MWBsetActiveCodes: function(activeCodes) {
    cordova.exec(function(){}, function(){}, "MWBarcodeScanner", "setActiveCodes", [activeCodes]);
 },

 /**
    * Set active subcodes for given code group flag.
    * Subcodes under some decoder type are all activated by default.
    *
    * @param[in]       codeMask                Single decoder type/group (MWB_CODE_MASK_...)
    * @param[in]       subMask                 ORed bit flags of requested decoder subtypes (MWB_SUBC_MASK_)
    */
 MWBsetActiveSubcodes: function(codeMask, activeSubcodes) {
    cordova.exec(function(){}, function(){}, "MWBarcodeScanner", "setActiveSubcodes", [codeMask, activeSubcodes]);
 },

 /**
    * MWBsetFlags configures options (if any) for decoder type specified in codeMask.
    * Options are given in  flags as bitwise OR of option bits. Available options depend on selected decoder type.
    *
    * @param[in]   codeMask                Single decoder type (MWB_CODE_MASK_...)
    * @param[in]   flags                   ORed bit mask of selected decoder type options (MWB_FLAG_...)
    */
 MWBsetFlags: function(codeMask, flags) {
    cordova.exec(function(){}, function(){}, "MWBarcodeScanner", "setFlags", [codeMask, flags]);
 },

 /**
    * This function enables some control over scanning lines choice for 1D barcodes. By ORing
    * available bit-masks user can add one or more direction options to scanning lines set.
    * @n           - MWB_SCANDIRECTION_HORIZONTAL - horizontal lines
    * @n           - MWB_SCANDIRECTION_VERTICAL - vertical lines
    * @n           - MWB_SCANDIRECTION_OMNI - omnidirectional lines
    * @n           - MWB_SCANDIRECTION_AUTODETECT - enables BarcodeScanner's
    *                autodetection of barcode direction
    *
    * @param[in]   direction               ORed bit mask of direction modes given with
    *                                      MWB_SCANDIRECTION_... bit-masks
    */
 MWBsetDirection: function(direction) {
    cordova.exec(function(){}, function(){}, "MWBarcodeScanner", "setDirection", [direction]);
 },

 /**
    * Sets rectangular area for barcode scanning with selected single decoder type.
    * After MWBsetScanningRect() call, all subseqent scans will be restricted
    * to this region. If rectangle is not set, whole image is scanned.
    * Also, if width or height is zero, whole image is scanned.
    *
    * Parameters are interpreted as percentage of image dimensions, i.e. ranges are
    * 0 - 100 for all parameters.
    *
    * @param[in]   codeMask            Single decoder type selector (MWB_CODE_MASK_...)
    * @param[in]   left                X coordinate of left edge (percentage)
    * @param[in]   top                 Y coordinate of top edge (percentage)
    * @param[in]   width               Rectangle witdh (x axis) (percentage)
    * @param[in]   height              Rectangle height (y axis) (percentage)
    */
 MWBsetScanningRect: function(codeMask, left, top, width, height) {
    cordova.exec(function(){}, function(){}, "MWBarcodeScanner", "setScanningRect", [codeMask, left, top, width, height]);
 },

 /**
    * Barcode detector relies on image processing and geometry inerpolation for
    * extracting optimal data for decoding. Higher effort level involves more processing
    * and intermediate parameter values, thus increasing probability of successful
    * detection with low quality images, but also consuming more CPU time.
    *
    * @param[in]   level                   Effort level - available values are 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.
    *                                      Levels greater than 3 are not suitable fro real-time decoding
    */
 MWBsetLevel: function(level) {
    cordova.exec(function(){}, function(){}, "MWBarcodeScanner", "setLevel", [level]);
 },

 /**
    * Sets prefered User Interface orientation of scanner screen
    * Choose one fo the available values:
    * OrientationPortrait
    * OrientationLandscapeLeft
    * OrientationLandscapeRight
    *
    * Default value is OrientationLandscapeLeft
    */
 MWBsetInterfaceOrientation: function(interfaceOrientation) {
    cordova.exec(function(){}, function(){}, "MWBarcodeScanner", "setInterfaceOrientation", [interfaceOrientation]);
 },

 /**
    * Choose overlay graphics type for scanning screen:
    * OverlayModeNone   - No overlay is displayed
    * OverlayModeMW     - Use MW Dynamic Viewfinder with blinking line (you can customize display options
    *                     in native class by changing defaults)
    * OverlayModeImage  - Show image on top of camera preview
    *
    * Default value is OverlayModeMW
    */
 MWBsetOverlayMode: function(overlayMode) {
    cordova.exec(function(){}, function(){}, "MWBarcodeScanner", "setOverlayMode", [overlayMode]);
 },

 /**
    * Enable or disable high resolution scanning. It's recommended to enable it when target barcodes
    * are of high density or small footprint. If device doesn't support high resolution param will be ignored
    *
    * Default value is true (enabled)
    */
 MWBenableHiRes: function(enableHiRes) {
    cordova.exec(function(){}, function(){}, "MWBarcodeScanner", "enableHiRes", [enableHiRes]);
 },

 /**
    * Enable or disable flash toggle button on scanning screen. If device doesn't support flash mode
    * button will be hidden regardles of param
    *
    * Default value is true (enabled)
    */
 MWBenableFlash: function(enableFlash) {
    cordova.exec(function(){}, function(){}, "MWBarcodeScanner", "enableFlash", [enableFlash]);
 },

 /**
    * Set default state of flash (torch) when scanner activity is started
    *
    * Default value is false (disabled)
    */
 MWBturnFlashOn: function(flashOn) {
    cordova.exec(function(){}, function(){}, "MWBarcodeScanner", "turnFlashOn", [flashOn]);
 },

 /**
    * Enable or disable zoom button on scanning screen. If device doesn't support zoom,
    * button will be hidden regardles of param. Zoom is not supported on Windows Phone 8
    * as there's no zooming api available!
    *
    * Default value is true (enabled)
    */
 MWBenableZoom: function(enableZoom) {
    cordova.exec(function(){}, function(){}, "MWBarcodeScanner", "enableZoom", [enableZoom]);
 },

 /**
    * Set two desired zoom levels in percentage and initial level. Set first two params to zero for default
    * levels. On iOS, first zoom level is set to maximum non-interpolated level available on device, and
    * second is double of first level. On Android, default first zoom is 150% and second is 300%. Zoom is
    * not supported on Windows Phone 8 as there's no zooming api available!
    * Initial zoom level can be 0 (100% - non zoomed), 1 (zoomLevel1) or 2 (zoomLevel2). Default is 0.
    *
    */
 MWBsetZoomLevels: function(zoomLevel1, zoomLevel2, initialZoomLevel) {
    cordova.exec(function(){}, function(){}, "MWBarcodeScanner", "setZoomLevels", [zoomLevel1, zoomLevel2, initialZoomLevel]);
 },

    /**
     * Set custom key:value pair which is accesible from native code.
     */
 MWBsetCustomParam: function(key, value) {
    cordova.exec(function(){}, function(){}, "MWBarcodeScanner", "setCustomParam", [key, value]);
 }

 };
```

Invocation of this function from the file startScreen.js:

```
    function startScanning()
    {
        //alert ('Hello world!');

//        cordova.exec(function()
//                     {
//                        alert ('Success');
//                     },
//                     function()
//                     {
//                        alert ('Failure');
//                     },
//                     "RPGBarcodeScanner",
//                     "startScanning",
//                     []);

        scanner.startScanning(MWBSInitSpace.init,MWBSInitSpace.callback);
    }

    $(document).off("pagebeforeshow", "#startScreen").on("pagebeforeshow", "#startScreen", function(event, ui) {
        Apperyio.CurrentScreen = "startScreen";
        _.chain(Apperyio.mappings).filter(function(m) {
            return m.homeScreen === Apperyio.CurrentScreen;
        }).each(Apperyio.UIHandler.hideTemplateComponents);
    });

    startScreen_onLoad();
};
```

I made sure that the scripts MWBScanner.js and MWBConfig.js (MWBSInitSpace) are loaded in the startScreen.html file:

```
    <head>
        <title>
            startScreen
        </title>
.
.
.
        <!-- Raj -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="files/views/assets/js/MWBConfig.js">
            </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="files/views/assets/js/MWBScanner.js">
        </script>
.
.
.
    </head>
```

How do I fix it?

**EDIT:**

Loading of startScreen.js file:
StartScreen.js file is being loaded in StartScreen.html file in one of the  blocks:

```
    <div data-role="content" id="startScreen_mobilecontainer" name="mobilecontainer"
    class="startScreen_mobilecontainer ui-content" dsid="mobilecontainer" data-theme="b">
        <link href="startScreen.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="startScreen.js">
        </script>
        <!-- mobilebutton_2 --><!--
        --><a data-role="button" name="mobilebutton_2" dsid="mobilebutton_2" class="startScreen_mobilebutton_2"
        id="startScreen_mobilebutton_2" data-corners="true" data-icon="none" data-iconpos='nowhere'
        x-apple-data-detectors="false" data-mini="false" data-theme="b" tabindex="1">
        Scan
        </a>
    </div>
```

I could confirm that scanner.startScanning function is being invoked with the help of breakpoints as you can see in the attached snapshot.

I cannot attach the whole of MWBScanner.js file because it exceeds the text limit, hence I have added only the part of code from MWBScanner which is of interest.

Comment: When/where are you loading the startScreen.js file? Also, the MWBScanner.js file shown in the screenshot seems different from the one you posted.

Comment: @Archon - I have edited the question above to add details of where StartScreen.js file is invoked from. Also, I cannot attach the whole of MWBScanner.js file because it exceeds the text limit, hence I have added only the part of code from MWBScanner which is of interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that **"BarcodeScanner"** was already defined somewhere else in the project and I had a hard time to figure this out!